# Retrieving data from firebase - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can not retrieve my Firebase data any more. The function checkForUpdates has a problem with observe(.value) .

this is my db:
[image]

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!        


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        ref = Database.database().reference()
        checkForUpdates()
    }

func checkForUpdates(){
ref.child("update").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            let update_var = snapshot.value as! String
            if update_var == "Y"{
                self.pageListCore = []
                self.retrieveDataFromCore(update: "Y")
                self.ref.child("update").setValue("N")
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Please show complete structure of update node.

Comment: I have updated my structure

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make your firebase database reference as below:

```
// Get your project database url from firebase console
let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "your project database url here")
```